# How to write a test, without mocking the repository in nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, nestjs

I've started working on a small project and I'm now in the process of writing tests for this project, But the problem now I'm facing is related to injecting the repository. I have the following code in beforeEach function

```
const moduleFixture = await Test.createTestingModule({
            controllers:[CustomersController],
            providers:[
                CustomersService,
                {
                    provide: getRepositoryToken(File),
                    useValue: Repository
                },
            ]
        }).compile();
```

And I have a test which it calls an endpoint, Now every time I run the tests, This error is showing up

```
Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
```

And it's obvious because I have a code in my CustomerService class, `this.fileRepository.find()`, And the reason it throws the error because the file repository has no methods which any other repository should have. [image]

I'll appreciate any help, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to use `Repository` you should be using `useClass` instead of `useValue`. [You can see several examples of Repository mocking in this GitHub repo](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs)

Comment: I dont want to mock the repository, i want to insert data into the database. Is this possible?

Comment: Okay, I have moved the ormconfig.json and move all of the configuration into the app.module, Now it's working, thanks for the help.